# How to open dynamically formed hyperlink as Popup

Tags: knockout.js

I am forming the hyperlink using knock out. Now i have to open the link as popup. 
Please find the code snippet below

```
 <a data-bind="attr: { href:'/Home/TechnicianData?logId=' + $data.LoginId}">
                                More tests...
                            </a>
```

Comment: Why cant you simply add `target="_blank"` to the element?

Comment: when you say popup, do you mean a new browser window, or some kind of modal dialog?

Comment: I want open the page as popu by using window.open

Answer (score 0):

Not really a knockout question, it's an HTML question, you just happen to be using knockout ;)

```
<a target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href:'/Home/TechnicianData?logId=' + $data.LoginId}">
   More tests...
</a>
```

Comment: I want to open this as popup window not in new tab

Comment: This will cause a html validation error: "Attribute is only allowed where 'href' is present" as the link is dynamically formed.

Comment: @Viqas you could get around that by giving it an href attribute which will be overwritten. It's not really a problem with modern browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I believe the easiest way is binding the "click" event to a function. Like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $root.myFunction">Link Content</a>
```

JS

```
function YourViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   //...
   self.myFunction = function (data) {
       window.open('/Home/TechnicianData?logId=' + data.LoginId);
   };
};
```