# KnockoutJs link only opens if i open on a new tab

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a databinding below, which I can successfully right click and open on a new tab. But a normal click does not actually open that link. Anyone knows what I could be missing or doing wrong here?

I am using KnockoutJS

`<div data-bind="attr: { \'class\': \'kgCellText colt\' + $index()}"><a href="#" data-bind="attr: {\'href\': $url, \'_target\': \'blank\'}, text: Text on top of url"></div>`

Comment: You have the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56966808/4065876.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what to say as this basically just works?

NOTE: (this won't work on stackoverflow because they block opening new windows (block popups policy)) (see https://jsfiddle.net/Ltnbcxf6/2/)

```js
class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
    this.first = {
      url: ko.observable(),
      text: ko.observable(),
      target: ko.observable()
    };
    
    setTimeout(() => this.load(this.first), 300);
  }
  
  load(item) {
    item.url('http://www.myfakeurltestforjsfiddle.com');
    item.text('fake url test');
    item.target('_blank');
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-bind="  
  attr: {
      href: $root.first.url,
      target: $root.first.target
  },
  text: $root.first.text"></a>
```