# Knockout "html" not rendering target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a questing about knockout not rendering html attributes properly.
I have a span tag that gets populated with data using knockout JS.

```
<span id="s34" data-bind="html: $parent.Branch.TextComments"></span>
```

TextComments is dynamic and sometimes contain text only. Other times text and < a> tags. For example:

```
This is text example of TextComment. Access google at <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Goole link</a>. Thank you!
```

When the page reders, the link reders correctly as a url but when I click it, it doesn't open a new tab, it redirects the page to google instead of opening a new tab which target="_blank" should accomplish.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this solution to a similar question shed any light? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955704/how-to-open-button-link-in-new-tab-using-knockout-data-bind

Comment: Perhaps knockout is configured to only allow Strict attributes? In Strict syntaxes [the `target` attribute was disallowed](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#target). If you can set HTML 5 to be the target, that might help. Since I don't know knockout, I cannot point any further...

Comment: Marc, it is a span element and its content is dynamic. sometimes it contains urls, other times it is just text. Knockout "html" attribute is perfect for all scenarios and it does show urls in the middle of text but it just doesn't honor target="_blank". It doesn't open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious if it really doesnt work.

I set up this minimal code snippet and everything works as expected in my local environment

```js
var system = {
  viewModel:function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.texts = ko.observableArray([
      "text 21321", 
      'text <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"> with target blank </a> ',
      'text <a href="https://google.com" > without target blank </a> ',
      'text 789'
    ]);
  }
}

var vm = new system.viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:texts">

 <span data-bind="html:$data"></span> <br>
</div>
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"> Test stack-snippet target-blank </a>
```

So in this snippet the links do also not open correct for me, but maybe this is a snippet restriction. See the normal link i added with target="_blank" it also doesnt open in snippet. in my local environmet all the links with target="_blank" opens in a new tab while the other one does not

Comment: Opening the chrome dev console gives this error for me - `Blocked opening 'https://google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`or `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Comment: But do you get the same error in your environment too? Because if i use this code not in a sandbox it works